# Converting scikit learn feature representation into LibSVM format

Tags: scikit-learn, libsvm, xgboost

I've been using a bunch of scikit-learn Transformer classes to pipeline and combine features for point-wise ranking modeling and I'd like to convert these features into LibSVM format to experiment with XGBoost and other methods. Is there any easy way to dump scikit-learn features into LibSVM format? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for [`sklearn.datasets.dump_svmlight_file`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.dump_svmlight_file.html).